# Make a object render behind/trough another but make hide it if its behind some other object

Tags: unity, shaders, objects

So first of all sorry for this strange title...
I know it may sounds worse and a bit complicated...

But heres my problem :

My player belongs to the "Player" layer.
He stands somewhere on my map, which belongs to the "Map" layer.
When the falls trough the map he isnt visible anymore... but he should ( dont ask why... he just should ).
But the should still be hidden by other objects ( Walls, Trees, other players ).

[image]

Player is standing ontop of the ground.

[image]

He is hidden by the tree ( works fine ) .

[image]

But he also should be visible while in the ground... and than while hes in the ground he also should be hidden by the tree for example.

I already tried to modify the shaders by setting ZTest to Less or Greater. But this caused strange iusses ( Half of the player was rendered and he wasnt hidden by any objects ).
I also tried to modify the render que... but this doesnt worked somehow... it just didnt changed anything...

So what else i could do to achieve this effect ?
I really appreciate any help ! :D

Comment: Perhaps stencil shaders can solve your issues. Dont know too much about them, but it might be a place to start. Here's an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkcCWqifT9M&index=4&list=PLbQ_O1Ax-4i6l153cyHfifREYaM8llohM

Comment: @Dennis Thats interresting ! Thanks a lot :) Im gonna take a look at it !